# Is it possible to pass a function or sub as an argument in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to pass a function/sub name as an argument so that I can call it within another function/sub in Excel VBA. Is this possible? If so, what is the type I set it as? I tried setting as Variant but that didn't work. I'm not sure what else to try.

Here is a basic outline of the code I'm working on. Including my failed attempt at using Variant.

As you can see I'm trying to have waitingBBG check a different range each time and then call a different sub each time. That's why I want to be able to specify which sub to call after waitingBBG is done.

Update: I updated the code with Application.Run instead of Call

```
Sub part_1
    Dim calculation_rng as String
    calculation_rng = "A1"

    Call waitingBBG(calculation_rng, "part_2")
End Sub
```

```
Sub waitingBBG(calculation_rng As String, call_id As Variant)

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range(calculation_rng), "#N/A Requesting Data...") > 0 Then
        'Check every 1 second
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "waitingBBG"
    Else
        'Call rest of code
        Application.Run "'my_addin.xlam'!" & call_id
    End If

End Sub
```

```
Sub part_2
    Dim calculation_rng as String
    calculation_rng = "B1"

    Call waitingBBG(calculation_rng, "part_3")

End Sub
```

```
Sub part_3
    Msgbox("Success")
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't do that, the procedure is being invoked as VBA evaluates what the arguments are (i.e. it's trying to pass *the return value* of the funtion as the argument, and a `Sub` doesn't return anything). If you want to pass a procedure's *name*, then your argument needs to be a `String` that contains the name of the procedure you want to invoke. Then `Application.Run` can run it.

Comment: Also you since you are asking for a range in `waitingBBG` you will need to `Set` calculation_rng in both sub parts.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yeah I knew that my attempt above won't work even before I typed it out. The example was just to illustrate what I'm trying to do. I forgot you can use Application.Run on a string. I will try that and report back. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for pointing that out. I was just quickly typing up an example - it's not my actual code. My code works but I just wanted to know how to change it to call different functions using waitingBBG

Comment: I'm not *exactly* sure what you're trying to do, but I suggest you search "pass function argument vba" at the top of the page.  There are literally hundreds of results returned from that search, and some of them are most likely exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok so I've updated the code with Application.Run and passing the string name of the procedure that I want to call. That works! However, I noticed that now I'm getting an error "Argument not optional". I think it's because I added parameters to waitingBBG, which used to have no parameters at all and it's messing up the line ```Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "waitingBBG"``` Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @JohnnyBones Can you link me one of those solutions? Because I did do several searches before I posted my question and did not find any answers to what I wanted. I just performed the search you suggested and I do not see any questions that are what I am asking.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Your solution to use ```Application.Run``` instead of ```Call``` worked. Thanks! I also had to update the ```Application.OnTime``` line to reflect the addition of new parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MathieuGuindon provided the correct solution. Thank you!

Basically, I needed to pass the function name as a string and use `Application.Run` instead of `Call`

Also,

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "waitingBBG"
```

needed to be changed to

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "'waitingBBG """ & calculation_rng & """,""" & call_id & "'"
```

to reflect the changes.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub sub1()
Dim a As String
a = "hii"
sub2 (a)
End Sub
Sub sub2(val As String)
If val = "hi" Then

MsgBox (val)
Else
MsgBox ("sub2 else")
sub3 (val)
End If
End Sub

Sub sub3(val1 As String)
MsgBox (val1)
End Sub
```